# Google Maps - memory leak with dynamic bitmap markers

Tags: java, android, google-maps, memory-leaks

My app uses geojson to draw features on map. To draw feature:

```
for (GeoJsonFeature f : new GeoJsonLayer(googleMap, new JSONObject(geojson)).getFeatures())
{
  f.setPointStyle(getPointStyle(text,status);
  layer.addFeature(f);
}
layer.addLayerToMap();
```

To generate point (marker) style and set icon:

```
GeoJsonPointStyle markerStyle = new GeoJsonPointStyle();
int[] markers = {R.drawable.marker0,R.drawable.marker1,R.drawable.marker2,R.drawable.marker3,R.drawable.marker4};
bmp = Utils.drawTextToBitmap(getContext(), markers[status], icon);
markerStyle.setIcon(highlighted ? BitmapDescriptorFactory.defaultMarker(BitmapDescriptorFactory.HUE_GREEN):BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromBitmap(bmp));
```

`drawTextToBitmap` just generates bitmap with text on it:

```
public static Bitmap drawTextToBitmap(Context gContext, int gResId, String gText)
    {
        Resources resources = gContext.getResources();
        float scale = resources.getDisplayMetrics().density;
        Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(resources, gResId);

        android.graphics.Bitmap.Config bitmapConfig = bitmap.getConfig();
        if (bitmapConfig == null)
        {
            bitmapConfig = android.graphics.Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888;
        }

        bitmap = bitmap.copy(bitmapConfig, true);

        Canvas canvas = new Canvas(bitmap);
        Paint paint = new Paint(Paint.ANTI_ALIAS_FLAG);
        paint.setColor(Color.WHITE);
        paint.setTextSize((int) (18 * scale));
        Typeface tf = Typeface.createFromAsset(gContext.getAssets(), "fonts/fontawesome.ttf");
        paint.setTypeface(Typeface.create(tf, Typeface.BOLD));
        paint.setShadowLayer(1f, 0f, 1f, Color.WHITE);

        Rect bounds = new Rect();
        paint.getTextBounds(gText, 0, gText.length(), bounds);
        int x = (bitmap.getWidth() - bounds.width()) / 2;
        int y = (bitmap.getHeight() + bounds.height()) / 2 -8;

        canvas.drawText(gText, x, y, paint);

        return bitmap;
    }
```

My problem is that on some phones (not on every phone) this approach causes huge memory leak if there is big amount of markes to draw on map. Problem does not exists if I use static marker drawable from resources, but I need dynamic bitmap to add text on it.

Do you have any idea about memory leak cause? It seems map holds bitmap reference so it prevents garbage from disposing it. Even if map fragment is destroyed, map resources will be never released, so after displaying map few times, app stops working due to OutOfMemory exception.